# Translation for 'la douleur exquise'?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, vocabulary

I'm looking for a term for 'la douleur exquise'. What I want to capture is the frustration of wanting to be something that everyone loves but knowing you can never be that, where frustration means a weird balance between blissfully imagining you are that and knowing that not being it makes no real difference, but wanting to be it so bad you physically hurt.

Edit: Apparently there isn't a phrase that translates directly to describe this, so I'll just have to work on my descriptive language.

Comment: If anyone can translate _that_, I'll eat my hat. In my book 'la douleur exquise' tops the list of phrases untranslatable into English.

Comment: The closest you might come is saying that you're going through an [existential crisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_crisis).

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'self-directed'? It is unclear what is intended by this what it includes or excludes 2) Why do you insist on a single word? Note that 'douleur exquise' is both more than one word, and very metaphorical, so why not translate loosely with the 'exquisite pain of unrequited desire' or a variant on the Shakespearean 'sweet sorrow'?

Comment: @TusharRaj _Everything_ is translatable (or else nothing is), just not necessarily with the exact  non-defining charactersitics (must have seven syllables, rhyme with 'calliope', and evoke the mists of Savannah on a September morning).

Comment: @Tushar Raj: In the original French those words certainly [didn't have that specific meaning until recently](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22la+douleur+exquise%22&biw=1145&bih=807&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1980&tbm=bks). Every occurrence in that "pre-1980" search is French rather than English, and I don't see *any* of them using it in the current "Anglophone" sense.

Comment: @Mitch: I see your point and maybe you're right and I'm wrong, but I don't really agree. There are a lot of words I have trouble translating because they are tied to a specific culture or place. (I'm not saying this is one of them). Luckily, English welcomes foreign words and phrases with open arms, so it's not that big a problem. If enough people start using it, who knows, this phrase might be the next `touche`

Comment: ...but I'd have thought [*the bittersweet pain*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+douleur+exquise%2Cthe+bittersweet+pain&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20bittersweet%20pain%3B%2Cc0) is a close enough equivalent *in general* (it just doesn't have that *specific* meaning, which I suspect isn't familiar to the average Francophone anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Did not know that. Thanks. I only saw the phrase last year and fell in love with it.

Comment: @Tushar Raj: You'd need to ask on [SO French](http://french.stackexchange.com/) to be sure, but if I'm right (the French don't particularly recognise the usage) then it's not really a "translation" issue as such. It's just that it was convenient for Anglophones to appropriate a "general-purpose" expression and endow it with a highly-specific sense when ***we*** use it.

Comment: Everyone knows _Weltschmerz_, but the Germans also have _Ichschmerz_, literally "the pain of being me'. Sounds not unlike the OP's thingy. That doesn't help with an English term, unless we translate into an obvious, transparently teutonic, neologism, as people already do with "world-pain".

Comment: @TusharRaj I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm objecting to the straightjacket of translation as word for word. So Tahitians don't have a word for 'snow', does that mean you can't translate 'The Call of the Wild'? You translate one word with _many_ other words, you give an explanation or a picture. I've already made the point that there is no single word translation from 'la douleur exquise' even in French, because it already takes two words!

Comment: @Mitch, I'm thinking of a word that I can't remember, and paraphrasing the definition because a synonym search turned up no results. I'm not 100% certain that the word is English, it might be a loaned word or something.

Comment: @DavidPugh you're on the right track... I'm thinking of a sense of knowing how you want to be and feeling it can never happen.

Comment: Sehnsucht (German) or saudade (Portuguese) or pining (English) are in the ballpark, but I don't think touch the nuances induced by 'exquise'. Look up translations synonyms of those.

Comment: Also, what do you want to get with 'self-directed'? I'm not sure I follow the nuance you want there.

Comment: I asked a similar question before: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167528/a-word-for-the-heart-wrenching-pain-of-wanting-someone-you-cant-have

Comment: @ermanen I actually minored in French, so I know the term and I get that it's not actually common in Francolinguistic pop culture (very similar to 'sweet sorrow' in today's English), but I really wanted an existential version of the same concept for a project I'm working on. Thanks though!

Comment: @Stephanie: I see. So "'la douleur exquise" has several related meanings and you are asking an equivalent of a different sense than the one that I asked. Also, you can still wait for answers before giving up. It's just been 1 day. You can start a bounty later also to draw attention. I will try to help also.

Answer (score 2):

The closest English expression I can think of for what you're describing would be: **laugh, clown, laugh.**

It's an English translation of the Italian, "Ridi, Pagliaccio," a line from Leoncavallo's opera *Pagliacci.* It is sometimes used in a literal sense, to refer to a performing artist; however, it can also be used in a broader figurative sense, to refer to anyone who puts on a cheerful front to try to meet the world's expectations, even though internally they are deeply unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't looking for a translation of 'la douleur exquise' because I know what that terms means. I was looking for a nuanced term for angsting over self-identity in a similar manner as 'la douleur exquise,' where the person you want is an alternate version of yourself, and the absence of love is for yourself. This question wasn't answered, it was kinda sidelined by the argument over French semantics.

Comment: Did you mean to post this as a comment or edit to the question? You accidentally posted it as an answer.

Comment: I meant it to be a comment, but I went for the obvious text box! My mistake