# What is a single word to call someone who adores you?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I want a word to describe person Y who **adores** person X. As in this case, person Y **admire** person X one-sided. So what would be the word to call person Y?
A more specific context is when this person Y, a junior of person X, fell gravely ill and the cause is partially because person X been ignoring Y, so person X said something like: I had overlooked the sickness of (the junior who adores me)

Comment: I guess the main concern for picking the most fitting word is related to the reason of the admiration. Only you did not state that ;)

Comment: If you want something slightly more pejorative and sex specific: **fanboy/fangirl** is an option.

Comment: In my case those people are my *subjects*.  But the wrong verb is being used -- rather than *adore* is should be *worship*.

Comment: I think **crush** best describes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Smitten/Infatuated/Obsessed** might work.

**Smitten** and **Infatuated** could be similar to 'crush' which might transpire to a more serious and healthy admiration. Though these doesn't strongly emphasize the 'unrequited' dimension, they are often used in anecdotes which end in it.

**Obsessed** is the harshest and least healthy of the three.

If the requirement is: Y adores X but X dint notice due to the distant admiration then 
"I had overlooked the infatuation of X (over me)" could work. 
However, if X knew about the admiration and intentionally did not reciprocate and Y still fell ill 'obsessed' could suit better.

A few good examples for the usage of **smitten** under the context of love can be found here: 
https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/smitten

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with [**admirer**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20admirer)?

> someone who has a particular regard for someone or something.
>
> *"he was a great admirer of Mark Twain"*
>
> **synonyms:** fan, devotee, enthusiast, aficionado; supporter, adherent, follower, disciple
>
> *"a great admirer of Hemingway"*
>
> a man who is attracted to a particular woman or a woman who is
>   attracted to a particular man.
>
> *"she's got a secret admirer"*

All of those synonyms are at least a good place to start your search.

Comment: Or even *secret admirer* depending on the circumstances

Answer (score 3):

What about [worshipper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/worshipper?q=worshiper):

> A person who feels great admiration or devotion for someone or
>   something.

Or  [adorer](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adorer):

> to regard with the utmost esteem, love, and respect; honor.

Comment: Worshipper is a bit too strong in my case, I'll consider adorer, thanks!

Comment: Worship is indeed a synonym of adore, however worship is commonly used to express formal prayers to a deity. The difficulty lies in the inflation of the word adore, which originally meant a noble form of love. Adore now also means infatuated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this indicates stronger feelings than you are looking for, but I recommend looking to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167528/a-word-for-the-heart-wrenching-pain-of-wanting-someone-you-cant-have) and the accepted answer.

"The term **lovelorn** addresses both the unrequited love and the emotional state of the person whose love is unrequited."

Answer (score 1):

The [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crush) defines **crush** as:

> A brief but intense infatuation for someone, especially someone unattainable:

---

The term *crush* is usually one sided towards a person who doesn't know about it.

> I have a *crush* on the secretary.