# Person who suffers from unrequited love

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a noun that describes a person A, who loves person B, but person B doesn't reciprocate. Person A suffers because he or she can't have person B and is not interested in relationships with others.

The shorter the word, the better (ideally -- single word).

Sample use in a sentence:

> It poured as if it rained tears of all *people who suffered from unrequited love*.

I need a substitute for *people who suffered from unrequited love*.

Comment: I’m tempted to offer _sucker_, but I don’t think that would be quite fair on poor A.

Comment: 'Lovelorn' is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A word for the heart-wrenching pain of wanting someone you can't have](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167528/a-word-for-the-heart-wrenching-pain-of-wanting-someone-you-cant-have)

Comment: a spurned person. unreciprocated  works but is long.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lovelorn) gives the meaning :

> miserable because of **unrequited love** or unhappiness in love

for the word '**lovelorn**'.

Also, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lovelorn)

> sad because the person you love does not love you

But note that both sources are defining the *emotion* (miserable and sad) of the recipient (or rather non-recipient). They are not defining the *state* of being in a situation of unrequited love itself.

However I think that the noun, **the lovelorn**, answers the OP as the question was about a 'person who suffers'.

Answer (score 4):

**Heartbroken**

A word that can be used for this situation is [heartbreak](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/heartbreak), defined as

> very great sadness and emotional suffering, especially after the end of a love affair or close relationship.

The corresponding adjective, *heartbroken*, fits your sample sentence perfectly, although the meaning is not restricted to unrequited love:

> It poured as if it rained tears of all the heartbroken.

**Lovesick**

If you want a word that is less generalized, you should consider [lovesick](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lovesick), defined as being

> sad because the person you love does not love you.

In that case, your sample sentence would be as follows:

> It poured as if it rained tears of all the lovesick.

Answer (score 1):

If you're striving for a more modern / comedic tone, you could say "all the friendzoned people".

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that sprang to mind was the simple approach: *unrequited lovers*:

> It poured as if it rained tears of all the unrequited lovers.

"[unrequited](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unrequited)" *(Collins)* being an adjective, it can apply to the people whose love is unrequited.

---

Side note: I'd move the "the" in that from before the lovers to before the tears:

> It poured as if it rained the tears of all unrequited lovers.

...but obviously that's a matter of style. With "the" before "unrequited lovers," I want something after, like "...in the world."

Answer (score 0):

You suggested brevity — preferably a single word.

I think a single word won't quite capture your intent.

I suggest the short compound "[It poured as if it were raining for all] the unrequited lovelorn."

Note the suggested revision to the earlier part of the sentence. It's good, as you've written it, but I would edit it to this, for better syntax and brevity, if editing it.

// Steve in Toronto //